# iOS: segue for iPhone only

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

Is there way to make show segue works only on iPhone? Some kind off turn it off at iPad? I have show segue on iPhone and it works perfect but on iPad I am using UISplitVC with same VC. And now every time when I choose something on left part of UISplitVC it make that segue instead my left UITableVC.

Answer (score 0):

Set an identifier for the segue in Interface builder, then in your view controller class you can use this in a method instead of presenting it in your storyboard. You can do that by clicking the class button in your view controller and entering it in "Storyboard ID" as shown here.
[image: Storyboard ID]

**IF YOU HAVE A BUTTON THAT YOU CLICK** to present the new view you can drag an IBAction from the storyboard to this method on the view controller you are presenting it from.

```
-(IBAction)launchIphoneOnlyController (id)sender {
    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {
        UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
    }
}
```

**Otherwise** make a call to the following method from wherever you want to instantiate the view from.

```
-(void)launchIphoneOnlyController {
    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {
        UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry not understand... I try to do something like ` - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showNewsDetail"] && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        DONT KNOW WHAT CAN I PUT HERE
    }
    
} `

Comment: And I think that presentViewController it's more like modal presentation I need show segue old push.

Comment: @user3742622 Updated with more details. If this doesn't help you; post some of your code and I'll take a look at what might be happening.

Comment: @user3742622 I personally don't use storyboards anymore unless I'm whipping something together really quick, but I end up discarding them most times anyways later in the process.

Comment: Sorry man ((( I really don't understand this part of advice "you can use this in a method instead of presenting it in your storyboard". What is "this method"? So I set an identifier for the segue 'showNewsDetail'. View Controller is my custom class of UITableViewController.

Comment: @user3742622 you'll have to look up the definition for method and I don't really know how to explain it other than by example. That void method and IBAction method are examples of what methods are. So you know in storyboards how you can drag from a button to a new view controller to present it easily? Instead drag from that button to the IBAction method. And yes for showNewsDetail you would click the view controller in the interface builder and edit the storyboard id in the class section.

Comment: I know about IBAction and buttons. But it's segue from UITableView. Ctrl+drag from UITableView cell doesn't create IBAction.

Comment: @user3742622 in didSelectCellAtIndexPath: check to make sure it's the index path you want and call the method [self launchIphoneOnlyController]

Answer (score 0):

In `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` check the seque ID you set in the story board and check `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)` for iPhone.

See [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSeguePerforming/shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:).